# Why intellisense does not show the range method

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, rxjs5

I am using rxjs based on typescript files as you can see as follow:
[image]

and included in my app.ts file:

```
import * as Rx from "rx/Rx";

var main = () => {
  $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
  $(".left-half").backstretch(["../images/lotus.jpg"]);


  var source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3);

  var subscription = source.subscribe(
    x => {
      console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('Completed');
    });

};

$(document)
  .ready(() => {
    main();
  });
```

but what confuse me is, visual studio does not recognize the range method as marked as red(as you can see on pic):
[image]

But it works like expected:
[image]

What is wrong with visual studio 2015?

I am using typescript version:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have the source code for `RxJS` inside your own project? Usually, you'd get your dependencies through `npm`/`bower`/...

Comment: what do you mean? I am pretty newbie.

Comment: The recommended way to [install RxJS 5](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html) seems to be `npm install rxjs-es`, since this allows TypeScript to find the associated type definitions through `npm`. However, you'll probably need to look up how to set up `npm` in a VS2015 project, since I don't use VS2015 myself... :-/